# Error with file_put_contents() when deploying web app using Laravel Vapor

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-vapor

I just updated my Laravel application to 6.0 to use the new tool Vapor.
However, after the deployment process end, I get this error when i access the app using the vanity url :

```
ErrorException thrown with message 
"file_put_contents(/tmp/storage/framework/sessions/cqDlEgxQSwsYKnBGpPjv94Dvzasa0ECmqF1Rl9xV): 
failed to open stream: No such file or directory"
```

Do you have some ideas about the reason of this error ?
Thank you

Comment: permission issues, have you checked the chmod + owner/group of the folders in question ?

Comment: possibly set the session driver to dynamodb

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while deploying a Laravel app using Vapor.

And solved it by

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=dynamodb
SESSION_LIFETIME=9999
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```